# Regular file download with Python scheduler and wget

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, wget, scheduler

I wrote a simple script which schedules the download of the file from web page once per every week with `schedule` module. Before downloading, it checks if the file was updated using `BeautifulSoup`. If yes, it downloads the file using `wget`. Further, other script uses the file to perform calculations.

The problem is that file won’t appear in the directory until I manually interrupt the script. So, each time I must interrupt script and rerun it again, so it’ll be scheduled for the next week.

Is there any chance to download and save the file "on the fly" without script interruption?

The code will be:

```
import wget
import ssl
import schedule
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datefinder
from datetime import datetime

# disable certificate checks
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context


#checking if file was updated, if yes, download file, if not waiting until updated
def download_file():
    if check_for_updates():
        print("downloading")
        url = 'https://fgisonline.ams.usda.gov/ExportGrainReport/CY2020.csv'
        wget.download(url)
        print("downloading complete")
    else:
        print("sleeping")
        time.sleep(60)
        download_file()

# Checking if website was updated
def check_for_updates():
    url2 = 'https://fgisonline.ams.usda.gov/ExportGrainReport/default.aspx'
    html = urlopen(url2).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    text_to_search = soup.body.ul.li.string
    matches = list(datefinder.find_dates(text_to_search[30:]))
    found_date = matches[0].date()
    today = datetime.today().date()
    return found_date == today


schedule.every().tuesday.at('09:44').do(download_file)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: what do you mean by script interruption? which error do you getting? and what you mean by checking file update?

Comment: Try with `wget.download(url, out=output_directory)`

Comment: Firstly, usually file is updated at let’s say 09:00, but sometimes it could be updated two-three-five minutes later. But, in html tag they wrote “Updated on DATE TIME”, so I’m extracting this DATE and TIME string representation using BeautifulSoup from tag, convert it to date and compare with today date to be sure the file was updated. @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη

Comment: On script interruption. Currently, I’m running the script via PyCharm. As I mention, when the script is running the downloaded file won’t appear in the folder. So, I must click “Stop” and terminate the script. After that, the file will appear in the folder. And to schedule download one more time, I need again click on “run” again. @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the output directory. I think that unless doing this, PyCharm saves in temp directory somewhere, and when you stop the script PyCharm copy it.

Change to:

```py
wget.download(url, out=output_directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following clue you should be able to solve your issue:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib3

urllib3.disable_warnings()


def main(url):
    r = requests.head(url, verify=False)
    print(r.headers['Last-Modified'])


main("https://fgisonline.ams.usda.gov/ExportGrainReport/CY2020.csv")
```

Output:

```
Mon, 28 Sep 2020 15:02:22 GMT
```

Now you can run your script via `Cron` job daily at the time which you prefer and looping over the file `headers` `Last-Modified` until it becomes equal to today's date and then download the file.

Be informed I used `head` request which will be 100x speedy to track it. and then you can use `requests.get`

> I prefer to work under the same session as well

Comment: Thanks a lot! Switched to requests from Beautiful Soup and it's faster, indeed.